# Resizing a child canvas in Flex

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml

I'm trying to figure out how to resize a child canvas but I can't quite figure it out.

I have a bunch of mini canvas' around a parent canvas like this:

```
<mx:Canvas width="10" height="10" backgroundColor="#040404" top="0" left="0" id="anchorTL" />
    <mx:Canvas width="10" height="10" backgroundColor="#040404" right="0" top="0" id="anchorTR" />
    <mx:Canvas width="10" height="10" backgroundColor="#040404" horizontalCenter="0" top="0" id="anchorTM" />
    <mx:Canvas width="10" height="10" backgroundColor="#040404" verticalCenter="0" left="0" id="anchorML" />
    <mx:Canvas width="10" height="10" backgroundColor="#040404" left="0" bottom="0" id="anchorBL" />
    <mx:Canvas width="10" height="10" backgroundColor="#040404" horizontalCenter="0" bottom="0" id="anchorBM" />
    <mx:Canvas width="10" height="10" backgroundColor="#040404" bottom="0" right="0" id="anchorBR" />
    <mx:Canvas width="10" height="10" backgroundColor="#040404" right="0" verticalCenter="0" id="anchorMR" />
```

One for each type of resize (top left, bottom right, etc.)

How would I get these to resize the canvas on click and hold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's already a component out there that'll do this for you (I've tried coding this up before too, it's not as simple as it seems on the surface).

http://www.objecthandles.com/

^ Let me know if that works for you or if you have a more specific need.